# How to fix camera Permission denail

Tags: android, android-sqlite

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.systems.subrapos, PID: 3637
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity } from ProcessRecord{4010923 3637:com.systems.subrapos/u0a320} (pid=3637, uid=10320) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1715)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1668)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3175)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1520)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4399)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4357)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
        at com.systems.subrapos.activity.ProductAddStep3Activity.openCamera(ProductAddStep3Activity.java:246)
        at com.systems.subrapos.activity.ProductAddStep3Activity.access$000(ProductAddStep3Activity.java:29)
        at com.systems.subrapos.activity.ProductAddStep3Activity$1.onClick(ProductAddStep3Activity.java:78)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22465)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6393)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

Request the permission:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, arrayOf("permission"), requestCode)
```

In the calling activity:

```
@Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
      @NonNull String[] permissions,
      @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

      if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, "permission") == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      // start intent
      }
...
}
```

If the user has already granted permission you won't have to request it.

Make sure that you enter the permission you are missing :) Please don't forget to set my answer as approved if this helped :) Or get back to me if it doesn't!

Comment: Thanks for your comment.but here i am use this process that is....


    private void openCamera() {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);


    }

Comment: protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) return;

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imagephotoButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Answer (score 0):

**Here in detail**,

- If the Android mobile is running Marshmallow or higher versions. For permissions like ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, you are supposed to ask during runtime.
- You can check Android version using

  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
  //then request for respective permission
  }
- Here is the link to runtime permission from official site https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: My mobile version is Nougat.and i am used to open the camera this code  private void openCamera() {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);


    }

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this,
private void openCamera() { 

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermission();
    }
} 

public void requestPermission() {       
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission((Activity) context,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) this.context,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) this.context,
                    new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA }, Constants.PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA);              
        } else {
        //This will request for permisson
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) this.context,
                    new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA }, Constants.PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA);              
        }
    }       
}   

//Callback for requestPermissions
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) { 
            case Constants.PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA: {             
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.i("open camera permission has been granted");      
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);           
                } else {
                    Log.i("open camera permission has been denied");
                    //Dont call camera intent app will crash                    
                }
                return;
            }          
        }
    }
```

Comment: when i am using this code there face a problem that is Constants.It could not solve anyhow.How can  i do now.